# Does longitude and latitude change with height?

Tags: geolocation

I am developing an application for 'phone and i would like to know if the longitude and latitude change with height?For example within a building if we move to north east corner room in each floor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you have an other value for height : [altitude](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altitude).

when you are in a building, with GPS, you can know how you are precisely.

For sample, in an elevator, your latitude, and your longitude don't change, your altitude change. with this third value, you can know which floor you are.

In general, you have also two other values :

- horizontal accuracy  : precision for longitude/ latitude.
- vertical accuracy    : precision for altitude.

For more details, you can see [this article](http://www.cienciaviva.pt/latlong/anterior/gps.asp?accao=changelang&lang=en), explain all GPS terms

Answer (score 2):

Longitude and lattitude can be supposed as a grid on a sphere  upon which we are standing.If you start jumping on your place only thing that will change with respect to the grid is height and and not the cordinates.

So longitude and latitude are independent of height.

Comment: I want to differentiate when a person is in 2nd floor Northeast room or 3rd floor northeast room.So altitude helps to differentiate this ?

Comment: Due to geometrical  reasons GPS are inherently less accurate in determining elevation.

Comment: @TimChild when converting from [lat,long,altitude]  to a 2d,2channel array representing the projection of lat,lng,altitude to [y,x,z].
Will the conversion contain an additional loss of precision in the altitude too?